# Got "undefined method `split'" when installing gem dm-mysql-adapter

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the gem dm-mysql-adapter with the following
command:

```
gem install dm-mysql-adapter -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql
--with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql
```

and got this result:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dm-mysql-adapter:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql
--with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
  --with-mysql-config
extconf.rb:43:in `': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
(NoMethodError)


Gem files will remain installed in
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_mysql-0.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/do_mysql-0.10.2/ext/do_mysql/gem_make.out
```

Has anyone experience the same problem? What should I do to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same problem. I'm on OS X 10.6 with the latest MySQL 5.1 package from dev.mysql.com.

Anyway, it turns out the fix was really simple, I just needed to add the mysql bin directory to my path:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Then, from the same command prompt (because the path only gets changed for that session), I installed the gem with the following command:

```
sudo sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install dm-mysql-adapter
```

I appreciate that this question is 3 months old, but this page is the top hit for 'can't install dm-mysql-adapter on osx', and hopefully this will help somebody out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to install it with parameters above, like @Deche and ran into the same error, your solution worked fine - but it's surprising, as mysql should be in my PATH already :/

Comment: i have a same error.
In my case mysql install by source compile.
this solution is worked fine. 
cent OS machine .bashrc put PATH and gem install worked.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac Big Sur (11.6.2), first running

```
brew install mysql
```

and then runnimg the gem command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to install `mysql-client` first. At the end of install brew tells where `/bin` is - you may need to replace it

```
brew install mysql-client
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: I get the error "Error: No formulae found in taps" when running the "brew install" command.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when running `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.4` on Manjaro.

I solved it by running `sudo pacman -S mysql`